# DockerFile: Containerising python do not allow execute further commands

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

This is my DockerFile

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code

# command to run on container start
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/xyz-agent
```

And when I execute the following command -
`docker -v build .` the docker builds successfully and I don't get any error. This is the output -

```
Step 1/3 : FROM python:3.8
3.8: Pulling from library/python
b9a857cbf04d: Already exists 
d557ee20540b: Already exists 
3b9ca4f00c2e: Already exists 
667fd949ed93: Already exists 
4ad46e8a18e5: Already exists 
381aea9d4031: Pull complete 
8a9e78e1993b: Pull complete 
9eff4cbaa677: Pull complete 
1addfed3cc19: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:fe08f4b7948acd9dae63f6de0871f79afa017dfad32d148770ff3a05d3c64363
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.8
 ---> b0358f6298cd
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Running in 486aaa8f33ad
Removing intermediate container 486aaa8f33ad
 ---> b798192954bd
Step 3/3 : CMD ls
 ---> Running in 831ef6e6996b
Removing intermediate container 831ef6e6996b
 ---> 36298963bfa5
Successfully built 36298963bfa5
```

But when I login inside the container using terminal. I don't see the directory created.
Same goes for other commands as well. Doesn't throw error, doesn't create anything.
NOTE: I'm using Docker for Desktop with Kubernetes running.

Answer (score 1):

For creating a directory inside a container it is better to use the `RUN` command and specify `-p` parameter for `mkdir` to create the parent directories.

You can also try to build your container via docker-compose.yml which contains

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  python-app:
    build: .
    container_name: <your_python_container_name>
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
      - <path_on_host_for_share>:/code
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

and build your container with `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you create your container from the newly built image ?

Let's take a look again at the whole process:

We have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code

# command to run on container start
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/xyz-agent
```

In the directory where `Dockerfile` is placed, we run:

```
docker build .
```

Then we run:

```
docker images
```

which shows us our newly built image:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>       <none>    775e0c698e81   29 seconds ago   882MB
python       3.8       b0358f6298cd   6 days ago       882MB
```

Now we need to tag our newly created image:

```
docker tag 775e0c698e81 my-python:v1
```

When we run `docker images` again it shows us:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
my-python    v1        775e0c698e81   About a minute ago   882MB
python       3.8       b0358f6298cd   6 days ago           882MB
```

Let's run a new container from this image and check whether our directory has been successfully created:

```
$ docker run -ti my-python:v1 /bin/bash
root@6e93ed4a6e94:/code# pwd
/code
root@6e93ed4a6e94:/code# ls -ld /tmp/xyz-agent
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 19 14:58 /tmp/xyz-agent
root@6e93ed4a6e94:/code#
```

As you can see above, `/tmp/xyz-agent` directory is in it's place as expected. I hope this helps you figure out where you are making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

CMD is a runtime instruction. How are you running your container? If you are doing anything like `docker run -it 36298963bfa5 bash` you are effectively overwriting the CMD-instruction with `bash`.

So switch the CMD to RUN action to create the directory already on the image building phase.

Answer (score 0):

Why you mkdir in CMD?

[The CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

The right way is to change CMD to RUN, means that mkdir in docker image, and then you will see the folder in any container from this image.